# Angular 6 Datatables Add click event for button

Tags: angular, datatables

So, I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere about this.

I was trying to use [**this**](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way) the "Server way" which works great, until you find out the limitations. Like the "select" plugin does not work, or you cant use "expanding" tables

So, I need to go back to using Datatable natively.

Let's say I define my table like this

```
this.dtOptions = {
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback: any) => {
    this.myService.myEndPoint(dataTablesParameters).
    subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.attributes = resp.aaData;

      callback({
        recordsTotal: resp.iTotalRecords,
        recordsFiltered: resp.iTotalDisplayRecords,
        data: resp.aaData
      });
    });
  },
  select: true,
  order: [2, "asc"],
  columns: [{
      data: null,
      defaultContent: 'details',
      orderable: false,
      class: 'details-control'
    },
    {
      data: null,
      orderable: false,
    },
    {
      data: "skuPartNumber",
      orderable: true,
    },
    {
      data: "activeUnits",
      orderable: true
    },
    //{ data: "consumedUnits", orderable: true }
    {
      title: "Display Name",
      data: null,
      orderable: true,
      render: (data, type, full) => `<button (click)="testClick(data.id)">sdfsdf</button>`
    }
  ]
};
```

How can I listen for the button event? My assumption is the page is rendered (compiled) before the AJAX and data table completes?

I was able to do this in knockoutJS and durandal, but cannot figure this out in Angular

Comment: Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: I am adding the HTML(with a button and a click event) AFTER Angular has processes the page. How do I get the event to fire? Must be a way, I just dont know how to do it

Comment: I should have been more clear.. I need to re-bind (not sure the terminology) Angular. I need to be inside the “Angular” context, so I can pass data into the function from the row.. Like an id, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using server-side rendering you can define your click events on `drawCallback` ([docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback))

```
this.dtOptions = {
    ...
    "drawCallback": ()=>{
        //define your listeners here
    }
    ...
```

Comment: What exactly does "define your listeners here" look like? Thats what I dont know.

Comment: define event listeners for your button. something like `document.getElementById('idOfButton').addEventListener('click',testClick(5))`

Answer (score 1):

You can capture event in `drawCallback`.

```
let table = $('#example').DataTable({
      drawCallback: () => {
        $('.buttonClass').on('click', () => {  //click event on button with class `buttonClass`
            this.nextButtonClickEvent();
          });
      }
    });
```

Refer this demo which has table pagination https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-pagination

Comment: I should have been more clear.. I need to re-bind (not sure the terminology) Angular. I need to be inside the “Angular” context, so I can pass data into the function from the row.. Like an id, or something else.